# can standard action component fire an event on a LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, action

I have an action on my record page to update a field. Field tracking is enabled for that field. I developed a LWC that renders the history records for that field and it is placed in the same record page. This components get the data in the connectedCallback just once.
Is there a way that the action makes the LWC get the new changes without refreshing manually the tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wire handler for this purpose:

```
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

...

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ OBJECT_ID ])
async handleRecordLoad(result) {
  this.historyItems = await getHistoryItems({recordId:this.recordId});
}
```

This works because, whenever a record change is detected, your wire handler will trigger, causing the data to be refreshed.

Do not use `connectedCallback` if you need to react to changes, because `connectedCallback` only fires once each time the component is initially attached to the DOM.